# Issues with BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

There is an issue using BeanPostProcessor. The error log says the method josh() in productFactory class is missing but the class does have such a method and it is non-static. Below are the code snippets.

web.xml

```
<bean class="demoproject.productPostProcessor" /> 
    <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="demoproject" />
<bean name="ProductFactory" class="demoproject.ProductFactory" />
```

ProductFactory.java

```
public class ProductCreater{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("web.xml");

        Product copyProduct = (Product) context.getBean("joshs");
        System.out.println(copyProduct.getId());
        System.out.println(copyProduct.getPrice());
   }
}
```

ProductFactory.java

```
package demoproject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

@Configuration
public class ProductFactory {


    public ProductFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Bean(name="joshs") 
    public Product josh(){
        Product josh = new Battery();
        josh.setId("cdrw");
        return josh;
    }


}
```

productPostProcessor.java

```
package demoproject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class productPostProcessor  implements BeanPostProcessor{

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName){
        System.out.println("Before initializing .. : "+beanName);
        return beanName;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName){
        System.out.println("After initializing .. : "+beanName);
        return beanName;

    }   
}
```

Error log

```
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7b09df06: defining beans [demoproject.productPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,productFactory,ProductFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,joshs]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'joshs' defined in class path resource [demoproject/ProductFactory.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'ProductFactory'; factory method 'josh()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
```

Somehow the line  `<bean class="demoproject.productPostProcessor" />`  in web.xml is causing this problem since when I remove it everyting works normally. 
How can I debug this program and fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the name of the bean. The `postProcess` methods are supposed to return the actual bean itself. You're telling Spring to replace the `Product` bean with a `String` containing the name.

Answer (score 0):

As your code , I think you are trying to initalize the Product object using the factory method.If I am right , then first thing is that your method should be static and second thing that method should be specified in the bean definition,like below

```
<bean name="ProductFactory" class="demoproject.ProductFactory" factory-method="joshs"/>
```